# How can I perform a get request to my Database with a REST API in Java having the Requestparameters "columnName" and "columnValue"?

Tags: java, postgresql, api, rest

I'm trying to perform a get request to my PostgreSQL Database which is supposed to work as an adaptable Search. For this request I have the parameters "columName" and "value".
My Java Code is the following:

```
@GetMapping("/product/search")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public ProductList searchProduct(@RequestParam(name = "fieldName") String fieldName,
                                 @RequestParam(name = "value") String value
                                 ){
    ProductList productList = new ProductList();
    productList.searchProduct(fieldName, value);
    return productList;
}
```

and

```
public void searchProduct(String fieldName, String value){
    ProductManager productManager = PostgresProductManagerImpl.getPostgresProductManagerImpl();
    productManager.searchProduct(fieldName, value);
}
```

and

```
public Collection<Product> searchProduct(String fieldName, String value) {
    List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
    Statement stmt = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        connection = basicDataSource.getConnection();
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p."+fieldName+" = " + value);
        while (rs.next()){
            products.add(
                    new Product(
                            rs.getString("name"),
                            rs.getString("description"),
                            rs.getString("location"),
                            rs.getString("alcoholContent"),
                            rs.getInt("likes"),
                            rs.getInt("dislikes"),
                            rs.getInt("productID")
                    )
            );
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return products;
}
```

I tried some stuff out by now but nothing really made it work.
In my RestClient I request a get method with

```
/api/v1.0/product/search?fieldName=namet&value=beer
```

I hope that I described my problem well enough for some help.

Comment: You are searching for the fieldname "namet", while you only have a field "name".  But I guess you mean with fieldname, the column name right? So you don't have to declare it with p.   Can you try to make your query like this:"SELECT * FROM products WHERE" +fieldname +" LIKE '%'+value+'%'.

Comment: I tried it and it helped a bit but now i always get null as response from the api. But even when theres nothing in the database it should return an empty list

Comment: Be careful! This introduces a [SQL injection security vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You need to validate that the field name received exactly matches a column name in the table and use a [prepared statement and bind parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) for the value.

Comment: Doesn't an empty list always gets presented as a null value? It does work when you have a value?

Comment: When you execute the query in your postgres, does it return values correct than? When the query works it is indeed better to make it prepared statement. But that depends what you are doing this for. (maybe you are just learning..)

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-intro